# MySql - transfer a lot of records from one table to the other

Tags: mysql

I have a large table (~50M records) and i want to pass the records from this table to a different table that have the same structure (the new table have one extra index).

I'm using `INSERT IGNORE INTO...` to pass the records.

whats the fastest way to do this? is it by passing small chunks (lets say of 1M records) or bigger chunks?

is there any way i could speed the process?

Comment: Turn off indexes on the target table during the insert operation, then re-enable/rebuild them afterwards.

Comment: If you using Where, idexes (on source table) may help. On destination table indexes can slow down the process (becouse after every insert engie recompute indexes).

Comment: im using indexes on the source table and i need the indexes on the destination table

Answer (score 0):

Before perform Insert, disable indexes (`DISABLE KEYS`) (if you can) on destination table:

Reference can be found: [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Also if you not using transanction / relations maybe consider switch to MyIsam engine.

Comment: and adding/removing index force an alter table which will take a lot of time on my case